# Make a function with Calls counter

Tags: c#, .net

Question is simple: how to make it as simple as possible for calling code? My code is a bit stupid, but i see no way.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
class FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TResult> function;
    public int Calls { get; private set; }

    private FunctionWithCounter(Func<T, TResult> function)
    {
        Calls = 0;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public static implicit operator FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        return new FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>(func);
    }

    public TResult this[T arg]
    {
        get
        {
            Calls++;
            return function(arg);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FunctionWithCounter<double, double> func = (Func<double, double>)(x => x*x);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            double d = func[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(func.Calls);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

So i use indexer to call like this func[x] instead of func(x), and there's some difficultes (can't call like a void-method). But it's most simple i think. Any offers?

Comment: so what's the specific error, and where does it occur?

Comment: And what are you really trying to achieve? It's not clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet it looks like he's trying to count the number of times he invokes his property

Comment: @SamIam: That's what I suspect too - but it's always good to be clearer about the aim...

Comment: why are you doing this?  why not just have a counter in your function?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, and it runs as expected.  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: http://ideone.com/xRxVnN - works.
So i'd like to count function's calls and incapsulate it just in function

Comment: @SamIam - It looks like he wants a cleaner way to invoke the func deleagte. In C++ you could overload `operator()`, but you can't in C#.

Answer (score 1):

for the price of 1 extra line,  I'd restore it back to at least normal function syntax.  Also get rid of the implicit constructor, it doesn't really save you anything, and without it, the syntax look simpler.

```
class FunctionWithCounter<T, TResult>
{
    public readonly Func<T, TResult> Function;
    public int Calls { get; private set; }

    public FunctionWithCounter(Func<T, TResult> function)
    {
        Calls = 0;
        Function = x =>
            {
                Calls++;
                return function(x);
            };
    }        
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var callCounter = new FunctionWithCounter<double,double>(x => x * x);
        var func = callCounter.Function;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            double d = func(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(callCounter.Calls);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```